# is function tcsetattr() mapped to a file descriptor or a physical port

Tags: android, linux, serial-port

I've encountered a very strange problem in the developing of 232 communicaion between my android device and a 232 device. I want to set up the communication bewteen my MCU and a 232 device, the 232 device has baudrate 115200.

What i have done is as follows: 
I `open()` a port `ttyO0` and obtained a file descriptor `fd1`. I use `tcsetattr(fd1,TCSAFLUSH,termiosA)` to map `termiosA` to the `fd1`. The `termiosA` has baud rate 9600 so its not compatiable with my 232 device.

Later I destoried what has been created before and performed the above process again by changing `fd1` to `fd2`, and `termiosA` to `termiosB`. And the `termiosB` has baud rate 115200.

However, I found it's still not working. I guess the reason is that `tcsetattr()` function actually does the map between physical port and settings, rather than the map between file descriptor and settings. So the actual physical port in my CPU was mapped to the setting of `termiosA` first and was not changed again to `termiosB` due to some reason. Thus the communicatoin between MCU and 232 device fails.

Comment: Are you sure about that rate(125000)?

Comment: @dbasnett The number does not matter, i just made it. Now I've changed it to 115200 to avoid confusion

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what tcsettattr() does.  It does not **map** anything, rather it **configures** an interface based on the termios struct found at the pointer you pass in the call.